# Why would Guard-launched and manually-launched specs behave differently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, guard, cancancan

When I run view specs manually (`zeus rspec` or `rake spec`) I am getting errors raised if Devise or CanCanCan helpers are present in the view

> Failure/Error: <% if user_signed_in? %>
>
> ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `authenticate' for
>   nil:NilClass
>
> Failure/Error: <% if can? :update, @object %>
>
> ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `authenticate' for
>   nil:NilClass

When the same specs are run via Guard, no errors are raised and the specs pass.

Adding the following to the view spec causes both Guard and manually launched specs to pass.

```
...
@ability = Object.new
@ability.extend(CanCan::Ability)
controller.stub(:current_ability) { @ability }
controller.stub(:user_signed_in?) {false} 
...
```

(I also tried including `config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :view` in a support file but this did not appear to do anything)

1. Why would Guard-launched and manually-launched specs behave
   differently?
2. Are these controller stubs the 'correct' way to deal
   with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Why would Guard-launched and manually-launched specs behave differently?

The best way is to run Guard in debug mode: `bundle exec guard -d`. It will show you the actual `rspec` command being run. Then, you can compare that to how you're invoking `rspec`.

The second thing could be: you may be running different versions of gems. Try `bundle exec rspec` vs `bundle exec guard`. There shouldn't be differences. You can then experiment with `zeus`, etc.

> Are these controller stubs the 'correct' way to deal with this issue?

I'd say it's best to use Cucumber/Capybara for testing views. It isn't as fast and the effort to mock the views is probably just not worth the time.

But otherwise, it doesn't matter how you stub/mock as long as you're testing what matters. For views, I think that means testing to make sure the right instance variables are used to generate the views. Testing the actually html generated probably isn't too convenient.

Views change often, too - so too much testing there can be a waste of time with little gain. Even if you make errors in views, they're usually easy to spot, quick to fix and there aren't too many edge cases. (Those are usually handled by controllers). So again, using Cucumber+Capybara gives you more tools, more flexibility and enough coverage without sacrificing your freedom to change things without being forced to update tests as well.

The reason for devise helpers is to get sign_in and sign_out working. That's pretty much it. So if those don't work, you likely don't have the helper included.

> I also tried including config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :view in a support file but this did not appear to do anything

Are you sure that support file was actually included? Usually nowadays you have to do that explicitly in the `spec_helper.rb` file.